# Moving from PHP to C#. How to handle returning FALSE if function has no valid result?

Tags: c#, php

I am learning C# coming from a PHP background. What is the correct way to handle the problem below?

In PHP, because we are not bound by strict var types, we can return FALSE if a function is unable to return a valid result like so:

```
function hitPosition(){
    $offset = 10;
    if ( $this->hitPosition < 100 || is_int($this->hitPosition) ){
        return $this->hitPosition + offset;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In C# however, we are unable to do so. As seen in the invalid code:

```
Vector3 MousePositionOnFloor(){
    Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

    RaycastHit floorHit;

    if (Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, 100f, floorMask)) {
        return floorHit.point - transform.position;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note: The code here is only meant to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Doesn't look like PHP to C#. Looks more of JS to C#. And this is Unity3D Engine Classes lol.

Comment: The problem is, your skipping C# basics. You will not get far on just trying to experiment with the Knowledge of JS or PHP to C#. It is way different from the other. Unless you know JAVA which is very similar.

Ok so your problem is you knowledge in C# But I will add an Answer Pointer for you on how to solve the problem.

Comment: I did JAVA way back but I am not a pro and actionscript/flash which has some similarities. I am familiar with OOP.

Answer (score 3):

This is the typical example of the issues PHPs strange conventions cause (I know, opinion, but shared by many). Functions should return one (base) type and that's it. With objects it is always possible to return `null`, but with structs it's different.

There are some ways to handle erroneous situations.

1. Exceptions. That doesn't really apply here: not hitting the floor is not an exception, it is a normal expected thing.
2. Return value in an `out/ref` argument and return the success boolean. This also is a bit cumbersome and the code is clearer if the function just returns what you ask.
3. Known objects. If the return type is an object, you can have a singleton "null object" that you return on this occasion (like DBNull etc), which you can compare to. This doesn't necessarily work on structs, only objects.
4. Known values. I assume your Vector3 is floating point values, so naturally it would be simplest to just return `NaN` values in the coordinates when there is no hit.

So the fourth one is the logical: no hit, no numbers to give out. Of course if you would need more differentiation on why there was no hit found, you would need more complex structure. But since here there are only three options - found, not found, exception - it is quite simple.

So in case of no result being found (assuming XNA Vector3) just `return new Vector3(float.NaN)` and on the receiving side `if (float.IsNaN(vec.X)) ...` to determine if there is a valid result or not.

Comment: Do you mean something like "return new Vector3(NaN, Nan, NaN)"? On the function call side, we would then have to check for isNaN, is that weird? Can you add a code example?

Comment: @komirad Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Then just check for IsNaN and it's handled. For me it isn't weird, since the result doesn't exists and that is a good way to say it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 MousePositionOnFloor(){
Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

RaycastHit floorHit;

if (Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, 100f, floorMask)) {
    return floorHit.point - transform.position;
  }
    return null;
 }
```

Ok First This Line
`Vector3 MousePositionOnFloor()` <- You don't even have a Access Modifier for this so this make it a private as default and cannot be accessed by other classes or other object in your game that Have Scripts. If you are sure you want this to stay like this, make sure that the operation stays inside that script or else you will get an error trying to access it outside.

`Vector3 MousePositionOnFloor()` <- Again it says It will return a Vector3 so A Vector 3 needs to have a value of 3 pairs of float X,Y,Z but this line
`return floorHit.point - transform.position;` <- is a Vector3 so this should be Valid.

`return null` <- This is a Major Problem. Because you said you want to return Vector3 but you're Returning null. At lease change this to a blank Vector3 or do nothing in the calculation. What ever you do, you cannot return Null for Vector3. As you will get Null Exception.

Returning a blank Vector3 is like this `return new Vector3(0,0,0);` <- Notice there is a 0 added. Cause Unity3D Vector3 Does not allow a nullable value for x y z. Cause Transform Position is an Absolute Rule in Unity3d. ANY OBJECT NEEDS TO HAVE A TRANSFORM POSITION in the GameWorld. When I say Any Object, I mean Any GameObject. That exclude components.

Comment: Thanks. I already got most of it as I am familiar with and use OOP. The problem is in PHP, the convention is to return FALSE if something is not found and can be confused with an actual result like so: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

In C# however, the return type is strictly defined, so I am asking more about what is the typical way to handle it in C#.

Given that we return new Vector3(0,0,0). It can be confused with a valid hit at point 0,0,0. I need to be able to determine if there's a hit at all.

Comment: Then you just have to check first, if there is a Hit before determining the Position. Simply separate your `if` condition to your Method.